# Colorize filename according to svn status

Tags: svn, bash, colors, ls

When invoking `ls`, I would like to have file names with a different color depending on their subversion status. For example, an added file will be cyan, a modified file red and so on. Is it possible with the bare power of bash? Is there something ready on this regard ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to achieve that with pure bash (scripting aside).

You can quite easily get colorised file listing using scripts (bash, python, perl, whatever your poison). Here's a rather crude proof-of-concept implementation written in python : https://gist.github.com/776093

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

colormap = {
    "M" : "31", # red
    "?" : "37;41", # grey
    "A" : "32", # green
    "X" : "33", # yellow
    "C" : "30;41", # black on red
    "-" : "31", # red
    "D" : "31;1", # bold red
    "+" : "32", # green
}
re_svnout = re.compile(r'(.)\s+(.+)$')
file_status = {}


def colorise(line, key):
    if key in colormap.keys():
        return "\001\033[%sm%s\033[m\002" % (colormap[key], line)
    else:
        return line

def get_svn_status():
    cmd = "svn status"
    output = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
    for line in output.stdout:
        match = re_svnout.match(line)
        if match:
            status, f = match.group(1), match.group(2)

            # if sub directory has changes, mark it as modified
            if "/" in f:
                f = f.split("/")[0]
                status = "M"

            file_status[f] = status

if __name__ == "__main__":
    get_svn_status()
    for L in Popen("ls", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout:
        line = L.strip()
        status = file_status.get(line, False)
        print colorise(line, status)
```

Comment: For those still using svn.  
There are svn bindings for python, might be more elegant than running subprocess, and you could colorize other commands as well.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's a Gist](https://gist.github.com/517913) with the 3rd generation of a small script to colorize SVN output. It works perfectly for `svn status` commands. I just added `alias svns="/path/to/svn-color.py status"` to my `.bash_profile` and now I can type `svns` and see the color-coded output. The author recommends making `svn` default to his script.