# Svn command line ubuntu

Tags: svn, ubuntu

Is there a way to colorise the svn command line on linux ubuntu ? like Git ? a plugin or something like that.

So we can run for example :

```
svn status
```

and we get the status with different colors ??

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667887/colorize-filename-according-to-svn-status